# Basic Singly Linked List Implementation

Tags: java, linked-list

### Purpose

I wanted to try and implement a very basic Singly Linked List as a data structure exercise.

### Implementation Discussion

I know that the [Java LinkedList API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is quite
extensive. However, in this basic implementation, I just wanted to implement the `addAtIndex`, `removeAtIndex`, and
`get` methods (with the `add` and `remove` methods delegating to the `addAtIndex` and `removeAtIndex` methods).

Things that I could improve

- For the `addAtIndex` and `removeAtIndex` methods I special-case when the `index` is `0` - is there a more elegant solution?
- Do the exceptions make sense?

  - For the `remove` method should I check to see if the list is empty and then throw an
    `IllegalStateException` before calling the `removeAtIndex` method? Same thing for the `get` method?
  - Should I replace the `IllegalArgumentException`s with `IndexOutOfBoundException`s?

### Implementation

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class SinglyLinkedList<T> {

    public static class Node<E> {
        private final E data;
        private Node<E> next;

        public Node(E data, Node<E> next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public E getData() {
            return this.data;
        }

        public Node<E> getNext() {
            return this.next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node<E> next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(this.data, this.next);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == this) {
                return true;
            }

            if (!(obj instanceof Node)) {
                return false;
            }

            Node node = (Node) obj;

            return Objects.equals(this.data, node.data) &&
                    Objects.equals(this.next, node.next);
        }
    }

    private Node<T> head = null;
    private int size = 0;

    public SinglyLinkedList() {
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.getSize() == 0;
    }

    public Node<T> getHead() {
        return this.head;
    }

    public void add(T data) {
        this.addAtIndex(data, this.size);
    }

    public void remove() {
        this.removeAtIndex(this.size - 1);
    }

    public void addAtIndex(T data, int index) {
        if (index > this.size || index < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index value");
        }

        Node<T> currentNode = this.head;

        if (index == 0) {
            this.head = new Node<>(data, currentNode);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
            }

            Node<T> nextNode = new Node<>(data, currentNode.getNext());
            currentNode.setNext(nextNode);
        }

        this.size++;
    }

    public void removeAtIndex(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index value");
        }

        Node<T> currentNode = this.head;

        if (index == 0) {
            this.head = currentNode.getNext();
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
            }

            currentNode.setNext(currentNode.getNext().getNext());
        }

        this.size--;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index value");
        }

        Node<T> currentNode = this.head;

        int count = 0;
        while (count < index) {
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
            count++;
        }

        return currentNode.getData();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's looking pretty good so far!

A few things,

I would make the Node class private. This is an implementation detail and nobody using your list should need to know or worry about it. I would also remove any public facing methods that return a Node over a T. If you want them internally you can make them private. (The built in Java LinkedList uses a private Node class but we don't need to worry about it)

You could remove a lot of boiler plate getters and setters by making the Node class private. You can access the fields directly within your SinglyLinkedList class.

When someone passes in a bad index, I would prefer and IndexOutOfBoundsException over IllegalArgumentException. (this is what java.util.Lists do afterall)

As well as this, I'd also like to see a more descriptive exception message. Maybe say which index was used, and what the current size is of the list.

You've overridden equals and hashCode in your node class which is usually a good thing to do in general, but here you don't really need it. However you may like to keep it if you end up adding additional functionality that may rely on it.

I think special casing index 0 is perfectly fine. 2 distinct things happen depending on it being the first element or any subsequent one.

A nice toString method would also be good here, you could just use a StringBuilder or StringJoiner to do this easily.

Comment: Implementing `Node.equals()` can be useful when you want to implement `SinglyLinkedList.equals()`. You simply call `Objects.equals(Object, Object)` on the two head nodes and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Chatton has already explained the general unnecessity of making `Node` public, but I would like to point out a specific problem in your code: By making both `Node.setNext(Node)` and `SinglyLinkedList.getHead()` `public`, you are putting your list in danger of being corrupted, because with a reference to `head`, one has almost complete control over your object, more than you would probably like (only `size` remains inaccessible directly). So even if the class `Node` is `public`, you should still make at least one of these two methods `private`.

I also agree with chatton that, if you pass 0 as an index to `addAtIndex(int)` or `removeAtIndex(int)`, this is simply a special case and there is no more elegant solution for this. If the index is 0, the new node must be set by changing the reference of a `SinglyLinkedList`'s instance field (`head`). If the index is greater than 0, however, the new node must be set by changing the reference of a `Node`'s instance field (`next`). The classes `SinglyLinkedList` and `Node` are unrelated to each other, so using a common method to change that field is not an option. The most "elegant" way I could think of that does not handle both cases separately is by determining the field whose reference to change at runtime using reflection, and I doubt you would call this "more elegant" (at least I wouldn't).

I look at your `addAtIndex(T, int)` and `removeAtIndex(int)` methods and see duplicate code. Alarm bells ring. Even if it's just 3 lines. You could make a `private` method that returns the `Node` at a given index and call this method instead:

```java
private Node<T> getNodeAt(int index) {
    Node<T> currentNode = this.head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index && currentNode != null; i++) {
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }
    if (currentNode == null) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Nice try");
    } else {
        return currentNode;
    }
}
```

A final remark about the field `size`. Technically, the size of your `SinglyLinkedList` is not really a state of the object per se, but rather a value that depends on another field, namely `head`. So you represent the same property of your object in different fields, which is basically an invitation for bugs. You might forget to update `size` when you add or remove an element, or you might make another mistake that causes `size` to contain an incorrect value. The problem I mentioned at the beginning of this answer is an example of this. Even if the exposure of the list's head node and its `setNext(Node)` method is intentional, your object can still become corrupted because `size` will not be updated if someone simply modifies the list's head node. If I were you, I would remove this field and instead make the method `getSize()` calculate the list size based on the field `head`. True, this might make a call to `getSize()` more expensive than if the size were cached in a field, but this is not your problem but that of the caller. And if that caller is you because you want to ensure that the index parameter passed to `addAtIndex(T, int)`, `removeAtIndex(int)` and `get(int)` is valid, you can instead rely on `getNodeAt(int)` to throw an exception if the index is out of bounds, so you don't have to traverse the node tree multiple times.